# matplotlib figure still shows y-axis after using set_visible(False)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to completely remove the y-axis from a plot in created with matplotlib.  The code I'm using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

colors = ["windows blue", "faded green", "dusty purple"]
colors = sns.xkcd_palette(colors)
b = 4
for j, a in enumerate([(0, 'No skew'), (b, 'Positive skew'), (-b, 'Negative skew')]):    
    x = np.linspace(skewnorm.ppf(0.001, a[0]), skewnorm.ppf(0.999, a[0]), 100)
    y = skewnorm.pdf(x, a[0])
    plt.plot(x, y, label=a[1], color=colors[j])
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.legend(loc=2)
sns.despine()
```

This produces a plot with the y-axis ticks removed, but the axis itself still visible (shown below).  How can I turn this axis off entirely?

[image: Plot with y-axis still visible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly provide the `left` or `bottom` parameter to despine with `sns.despine`. By default, only right and top axes are removed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

colors = ["windows blue", "faded green", "dusty purple"]
colors = sns.xkcd_palette(colors)
b = 4
for j, a in enumerate([(0, 'No skew'), (b, 'Positive skew'), (-b, 'Negative skew')]):    
    x = np.linspace(skewnorm.ppf(0.001, a[0]), skewnorm.ppf(0.999, a[0]), 100)
    y = skewnorm.pdf(x, a[0])
    ax.plot(x, y, label=a[1], color=colors[j])
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.legend(loc=2)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also remove the axis and the spine directly with matplotlib.
If you remove the xticks or yticks by

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

the spines are still visible. If you want to turn off also the spines, so having no axis at all, you can use:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)       
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

And if you want to turn everything off at once, use:

```
 ax.axis("off")
```